# Swift 3 - MapKit Annotation Touch Listener

Tags: ios, swift3, annotations, mapkit

I searched on everywhere, but i could not find it. I want to below action.

**When I touch the annotation on the map, I want to change text on the view.**

I tried below code but this does not work. I simply change text on the screen when annotation pin clicked.

```
private func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView{
    hastane_adi_text.text = "HAstane"
}
```

You can see my "ViewControllerClass" below.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class HospitalControlloer: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var hastane_adi_text: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!

    @IBOutlet weak var randevu_al_button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var hizala_button: UIButton!

    let locationMenager = CLLocationManager()


    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {

        return .lightContent

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        randevu_al_button.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
        hizala_button.layer.cornerRadius = 10;



        let locationS:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(41.169425, 29.056801)

        let sd = MKPointAnnotation()

        sd.coordinate = locationS
        sd.title = "Sarıyer Merkez Hastane"


        let locationS2:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(41.097076, 29.05341)

        let sd2 = MKPointAnnotation()

        sd2.coordinate = locationS2
        sd2.title = "Sarıyer Baltalimanı Hastane"


        map.addAnnotation(sd)
        map.addAnnotation(sd2)

        self.locationMenager.delegate = self

        self.locationMenager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

        self.locationMenager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        self.locationMenager.startUpdatingLocation()

        self.map.showsUserLocation = true


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    }


    private func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view:  MKAnnotationView){

        hastane_adi_text.text = "HAstane"

    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func locate_button(_ sender: Any) {

        locationMenager.requestLocation()
    }




    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        let location = locations.last

        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)

        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1) )

        self.map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        self.locationMenager.stopUpdatingLocation()       
 }
```

Comment: Hi, did function `private func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view:  MKAnnotationView)` call when you touch annotation

Comment: no it is not calling how can do it. I am new on ios. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should change delegate func to

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
   hastane_adi_text.text = "HAstane"
}
```

and add  `map.delegate = self` at `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    map.delegate = self 
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you need to implement this method `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView)` and add your viewController as map delegate `self.map.delegate = self`

I hope this helps you